# Convergence in $\mathcal{S}'$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

In a course I am taking, we discussed the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and its (topological) dual $\mathcal{S}'$. When it came to the discussion of the topology on $\mathcal{S}'$, however, the professor only wrote

1. We say that a sequence $\{u_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $u\in\mathcal S'$ if $\langle u_j,\varphi\rangle\to\langle u,\varphi\rangle$ for all $\varphi\in\mathcal S$;
2. A map $\mathcal{S}'\to\mathcal{S}'$ is said to be continuous if it takes every convergent sequence to a convergent sequence;

and did not give a precise description of the topology on $\mathcal{S}'$. Judging from the definition 1, I believe that he was giving $\mathcal{S}'$ the [weak* topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#Weak-*_topology). However, I am having a hard time proving that the definition of continuity defined as above matches the continuity in terms of the weak$^*$ topology. If the weak* topology were first countable, the answer would be yes, but unfortunately [this is not the case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678785/prove-that-the-weak-topology-on-the-space-of-tempered-distributions-is-not-1?rq=1). I asked the professor this question but he said he didn't know the answer. So my question is:

- What topology, if any, do we usually give $\mathcal{S}'$?
- Is the continuity defined as above the same as the weak* continuity; that is, does sequential continuity of a map $F:\mathcal{S}'\to \mathcal{S}'$ imply the continuity of $F$ when we endow $\mathcal{S}'$ with the weak* topology?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately the topology "usually" put on $S′$ is the wrong topology namely the weak-star topology. The canonical topology to use for $\mathcal{S}′$ is the strong one. Also continuity for linear maps should be explained as for Banach spaces. $T:V→W$ linear between LCTVS's is continuous iff for every continuous seminorm $||⋅||_W$ on $W$ there exists a continuous seminorm $||⋅||_V$ on $V$, such that $||T(v)||_W≤||v||_V$ for all $v$. Using sequences for defining continuity is counterproductive and not pedagogically justified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather tedious question. Usually, in the theory of locally convex spaces, you give dual spaces the strong topology, i.e. the topology of uniform convergence on bounded sets (this coincides with the norm topologies in case of normed spaces). This topology is strictly finer as the weak(-star) topology, which is the topology of uniform onvergence on finite sets.

But now it comes. $\mathcal{S}$ and and its strong dual $\mathcal{S}'$ are Montel spaces, so on bounded sets, sequential and normal convergence coincide. As a convergent sequence is bounded, a sequence of distributions converges (strongly) iff it converges pointwise (weakly). This carries on to linear maps: They are continuous iff they are weakly continuous.

Comment: One has to be careful: A sequentially continuous linear map  from $(\mathscr S',\sigma^*)$ into another locally convex space need not be continuous (if, e.g., that other space is $\mathscr S'$ with the strong topology, the identity is sequentially continuous but not continuous).

Comment: You are right, I was only thinking of linear maps $\mathcal{S}`\to\mathcal{S}'$ carrying the same topology on each side.